# After Creating a NuGet Package to share common libraries that are used in multiple projects, I run into an error when I attempt to install the package

Tags: nuget-package

I have created a basic NuGet package using the NuGet Package Explorer. Inside of the package is some of the files that are commonly shared among many projects in our solution.

When I've attempted to install this package in Visual Studio's NuGet Package Manager, I received the error:

> "Could not install package 'Shared.Test.Package 1.0.4'. You are trying
>   to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author."

This is my first attempt at ever creating a NuGet package and I am somewhat a novice when it comes to creating these packages. I am unsure if I need to add dependencies/refrences to the Package via Package Explorer? If so how would I go about finding which ones I need to add if that is even the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Please see the two attached pictures below.
[NuGet Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlaWg.png)
[NuGet Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJXWd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is clear enough, you need to change you target platform (`Project Properties => Target Framework` to match that of the library you used in the `Nuget Package`.

In other words, the project that you created for your Nuget Package must target the same framework as the project you'r installing the package into.

Read More : [Docs](https://docs.nuget.org/create/enforced-package-conventions)

Comment: I am unsure of what Frame Work is used in my Nuget Package. I'm not sure I ever added one to the package when I made one. Is this supposed to be added to the meta data source XML file for that package? I attached a photo of the XML file for the package.

Comment: @JohnHanewich If you target the lower version, it will work for the newer. Don't you have a VS project for you Nuget ? Check the properties of the project.

Comment: Yes, under my project>properties>Target Framework says .NET Framework 4.5.2.    Now in the Nuget how do I make it match what my projects is? By editing the Nuget XML?

Comment: @JohnHanewich you can do that in the Visual Studio project properties for the class library from which you created the package.

Comment: Add something like this to my NuGet package XML?<frameworkAssemblies>
  <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.ServiceModel" targetFramework="net40" />
  <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.SomethingElse"  />
</frameworkAssemblies>

Answer (score 0):

[Error Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4OqP.png)

The issue has been solved.
See image link above.

**The issue:**

In my particular case, the Nuget Package threw the common error for "Could not install package 'Shared.Test.Package 1.0.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

---

**The Solution :**

Please see the linked image above to view folder structure. When building a NuGet package using NuGet package explorer, I was unaware of NuGet's Enforced package-conventions and folder structure which can be seen here.
[Enforced Folders](https://docs.nuget.org/create/enforced-package-conventions)

When building my 'simple' NuGet packages to store shared CSS/Scripts so we can pull them in too many solutions, I was placing my two folders, CSS, and Scripts into the package with out putting them into NuGet's enforced 'Content' folder. With out using the enforced folders like Content, Lib, and Net452 the package will not install correctly.

---

Along with folder structure inside the NuGet package, make sure to check the target frame work selected for your project is the same with any content your package may contain **if content is using .net framework.**

Example:
Package contains files that are built using .Net version 4.5.2. The package files should be contained in NuGets .Net folder using NuGet's naming conventions for folders.

Correct Folder Structure in package explorer.
lib>net452>file.dll

---

To check target framework for your project:

In Solution Explorer
Right-Click>Project>Properties

---